# LM317, principle of operation

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have found a schematic explaining a LM317, principle of operation.
The way I read the diagram, the non- inverting op-amp input (+) is always going to be at the 'INPUT' level,
and doesn't matter what the adjust voltage is.

I am wondering if they should have a resistor where they have the circle for the adjust current. Lower voltage on adjust would then lower the voltage on the non- inverting input.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your reading is incorrect. The circle with an arrow is a current source, not just a wire from the input terminal. That current will be constant, regardless of Vin. For practical purposes, the entire adjust current will flow through the Zener, and out the adjust pin.

Comment: So the voltage at the + input equals the voltage at the adjust pin + 1.25 volts.